# Trouble evaluating a limit

Tags: limits

I have this following limit:
$$
\operatorname{f}\left(x\right) =
\lim_{x \to 2k}\,\,
\frac{x\left(x - 2k\right)}
{\cos\left(\pi x\right) - 1},\quad
k \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
The obvious solution is to apply L'Hospital's rule twice, which seems to result in a constant, and hence the limit can be evaluated. However, I am told that this limit is indeterminate, and I am unsure as to how this may be possible.

Comment: Plugging x=2k into the expression, you get 0/0 thats why it is indeterminate

Comment: @Rico The expression is an indeterminate form but maybe who told you that the "limit is indeterminate" was referring to the fact that the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying L'Hospital once, we get

$$\lim_{x\to 2k}\frac{2x-2k}{-\pi\sin(\pi x)}$$

which is not an $\dfrac00$ indeterminate form and you can't apply L'Hospital twice.

Comment: Ahhhh of course! I was getting bogged down by when L'Hopital's rule can be applied. Thank you!

Comment: @Rico: it is good to fall in the trap. You won't forget anymore...

Answer (score 1):

Without L'Hospital:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 2k}\frac{x(x-2k)}{\cos(\pi x) -1} = \lim\limits_{x\to 2k}\frac{x(x-2k)}{\cos(\pi x-2 \pi k) -1}=\\
=-\lim\limits_{x\to 2k}\frac{x(x-2k)}{2\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{2}(x-2k))}$$
last one have $\sin$ in second power in denominator.

Answer (score 1):

With these questions I feel it is best to avoid L'Hospital's rule.  I often set exam questions that are impractical to solve  that way, but relatively trivial if you use common sense.  I know other lecturers do the same - they want students to understand what is going on, rather than using a black box.

Anyway:
\begin{align*}
 \lim_{x\to 2k}\frac{x(x-2k)}{\cos(\pi x) -1}=\lim_{x\to 2k}\frac{x(x-2k)}{\cos(\pi (x-2k)) -1}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{(y+2k)y}{\cos(\pi y) -1}
\end{align*}

setting $y=x-2k$.  However $\cos(\pi y)=1-\frac {\pi^2y^2}2+o(y^3)$

So our limit is: \begin{align*}
 \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y+2k}{\frac {-\pi^2y}2+o(y^2)}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac1y \frac{y+2k}{\frac {-\pi^2}2+o(y)}=\frac{-4k}{{\pi^2}}\lim_{y\to 0}\frac1y 
\end{align*}

which diverges.

Comment: In this case I would say that limit doesn't exist since RH and LH limits are different.

Comment: Note also that we don't need Taylor's expansion since standard limits suffice.

Answer (score 0):

As noticed we can apply l'Hospital only for one step to obtain

$$\lim_{x\to 2k}\frac{2x-2k}{-\pi\sin(\pi x)}$$

which doesn't exist since RH and LH limits are different.

Note also that for this kind of simple limits, it is preferable to proceed without l'Hospital's rule, notably by $x-2k=y \to 0$ we have that

$$\frac{x(x-2k)}{\cos(\pi x) -1}=\frac{(y+2k)y}{\cos(2\pi k+\pi y) -1}= (y+2k) \frac{y}{\cos(\pi y) -1}$$

with $y+2k \to 2k$ and since

$$\frac{y}{\cos(\pi y) -1}=\frac1{\pi^2}\frac{(\pi y)^2}{\cos(\pi y) -1}\frac1y$$

with $\frac{(\pi y)^2}{\cos(\pi y) -1} \to -2$ by standard limits, we conclude that the given limit doesn't exist since

$$\lim_{x\to 2k^+}\frac{x(x-2k)}{\cos(\pi x) -1} =-\infty \neq \lim_{x\to 2k^+}\frac{x(x-2k)}{\cos(\pi x) -1} =\infty$$